# Cannot get geolocation coordinates right away in openlayers 5

Tags: angular, geolocation, openlayers, angular6, openlayers-5

I am implementing a geolocation/position tracking functionality with openlayers5 and angular 6. Even though I dont get any errors and this seems to work fine, I dont get the coords right away. Here is my geolocation-related code.

```
ngOnInit() {
//initialize everything in the ngOnInit
    //set it
    this.geolocation = new Geolocation({      
      trackingOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      },
      projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    //handle errors
    this.geolocation.on('error', (error) => {
      this.geolocationerror=true;
      this.geolocationmsg = error;
    });

    //accuracy
    this.accuracyFeature = new Feature(); 
    this.geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', ()=> {
      this.accuracyFeature.setGeometry(this.geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
    });

    //position point
    this.positionFeature = new Feature();
    this.positionFeature.setStyle(new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#3399CC'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
          width: 2
        })
      })
    }));

    //track position
    this.geolocation.on('change:position', ()=> {
      let coordinates = this.geolocation.getPosition();
      this.positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ?
        new Point(coordinates) : null);
    });

    //on smaller screens toggle the geolocation on automatically
    if(window.innerWidth < 600){
      this.isChecked = true;
    }    

    //geolocation has its own vector layer
    this.geolocsource = new VectorSource({});
    this.geoloclayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.geolocsource,
      title:'location'
    });

  }//ngOnInit closes here


  //toggle geolocation on/off
  toggleGeolocation(checked){
    //erase any previous errors    
    this.geolocationmsg='';
    this.geolocationerror=false;
    ////toggled on
    if(checked){
      this.geolocation.setTracking(checked); //set on
      this.geolocsource.addFeatures([this.accuracyFeature, this.positionFeature]) ;
      this.geolocOn = true; // to show info in html     
      let center = this.geolocation.getPosition();
      //zoom there
      if (center){
        this.olmap.getView().animate({
          center: center,
          duration: 2000,
          zoom:16
        });        
      }
      //show the geolocation coords in html all the time
      this.geolocLiveCoords = this.geolocation.getPosition();
    }
    else{ //geolocation off
      this.geolocation.setTracking(checked);      
      this.geolocOn = false;
      this.geolocsource.clear();
      this.geolocLiveCoords='';
    }    
  }
```

and this is the HTML part

```
<label for="track">track position<input id="trackpos" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="toggleGeolocation(isChecked)"/></label>
<div  *ngIf='geolocationerror'>{{geolocationmsg}}</div>
<div  *ngIf='geolocOn'>{{geolocLiveCoords}}</div>
```

The checkbox is automatically checked for smaller screens.

In any case, even though I get no errors, **I have to manually check-unckeck the checkbox myself a couple of times in order to see the geolocation coords and for the whole code to work. It does not work the first time I turn it on, it gets no coords, so I turn it off and on again. After that it works fine, as it should.**

What is the problem here? How can I fix it? Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're only turning on the tracking when you call `toggleGeolocation` with `true` which, at this stage, only happens then you check the check-box. If you want it to start straight away, you should call it at the end of your `ngOnInit` method:

```
this.toggleGeolocation(this.isChecked);
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but even then, I have to manually check-unckeck the checkbox myself a couple of times in order to see the geolocation coords and for the whole code to work. That is the problem : In any case, I have to toggle a couple of times manually in order for geolocation to work. As if it doesn't work right away or it doesnt have coords the first time it is turned on. Thanks

Comment: Hi again. I know what causes the error. Geolocation takes some time to get the position, as it normally does. In that little time, the `if(center)this.olmap.getView().animate({` part of the `toggleGeolocation` function is false, does not enter the code block and it never zooms to that point. There is a point after a little while, but because of that `if`, the map never zooms there. Now, I dont know how to fix this, because none of `addFeatures` or `getPosition` have a callback that I can safely use. Any other idea on when to zoom after the geolocation actually has a point? Thanks

Comment: I had a dig through their documentation and couldn't find any way of getting a callback from it. Have you tried seeing if, after making the call to `getPosition`, the generic `geolocation.on('change', (event) => { ... })` gets fired? Or maybe you have to wait until the first time it gets fired before you can use `getPosition`? If they're not using that event then the only thing I can see working is using an interval timer to check and wait for a result.

Comment: Since this problem changed context, I started a new, more specific question. I also include a new solution that I tried(and failed). You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726230/wait-until-openlayers-5-geolocation-returned-a-value) if you like. Thank you for your time.